# Using column data as pattern for regexp match

Tags: regex, postgresql

Recently, we have changed from MySQL to PostgreSQL. Most of the queries have been translated except for the ones with the Mysql 'REGEXP' keyword:

```
MySQL (prepared statement):
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ? REGEXP identifier;
```

We have a 'table', and one of the columns is called 'identifier'. This 'identifier' column contains the actual regular expression pattern.

So, instead of 'hard-coding' the regexp pattern in the query, it looks-up the identifier column for the pattern.

In Postgresql, we need to use the '~' keyword instead of the 'REGEXP' one (which is MySQL only), but with Postgresql I cannot seem to extract the pattern from a column.

I've tried following queries without success:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'test' ~ "identifier";
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced


SELECT * FROM table WHERE "identifier" ~ 'test';
-> no results
```

for testing purposes I created a number of records where the "identifier" column contains '.*' as value (regular expression for match everything), but still I do not get the appropriate result.

Help is very much welcome, thank you!

Comment: Why are you using column  name in quotation marks? Try without them.

Comment: @sufleR It isn't the problem. Double quotes are used in postgresql to specify exact name of column/table/schema/function...

Comment: We need to see your actual regexp pattern. Please provide sample rows that fail for you in the question or as sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in one of the regexp strings? (As the error string says)

I've tested

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
WHERE 'cat' ~ t.reg;
```

And it works for me. Here is my SQL Fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f245c/3

The problem can be in different regexp interpretation. Details about postgresql regexp here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

UPD Also read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS for detail about postgresql strings. You need this to write regexp correctly.

Comment: Thanks Igor, I've read the postgresql regexp page. the actual regexp pattern should be correct (I use .* to test). Can I ask which version of postgresql you are using? because I tested your example and it didn't work for me: SELECT * FROM "Table1" t WHERE 'cat' ~ t.reg;
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced

Comment: @Freqo I tested for 8.3 8.4 9.1 9.2 . See the SQL Fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f245c/1 (You can choose postgresql version at the top of the page)

Comment: @Freqo: Can you reproduce your problem on sqlfiddle.com so that we can see exactly what is going on?

Comment: No, I cannot reproduce with sqlfiddle.com, it works over there ;)