# Postgresql regex match by end of string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this :

```
> create table sample(id int, identity varchar(20)) ;
> insert into sample (id,identity) values (1,'9822');
> insert into sample (id,identity) values (2,'129822');
> insert into sample (id,identity) values (3,'ABCD9822');
> insert into sample (id,identity) values (4,'1234');

------------------------
> select * from sample ;
 id | identity 
----+----------
  1 | 9822
  2 | 129822
  3 | ABCD9822
  4 | 1234
(4 rows)
```

I have a string like `0987129822` .
how to select on database to fetch all identities ends matches by this string ?
I need this result :

```
 id | identity 
----+----------
  1 | 9822
  2 | 129822
```

***Note*** : maybe this question duplicated , but i can not understand what keyword should i search on google .

Comment: ABCD9822 should NOT match?

Comment: @FrankHeikens , oh sorry , no , could not match

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using column data as pattern for regexp match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564369/using-column-data-as-pattern-for-regexp-match)

Comment: you can also swap the pattern using `like`: `select * from sample where '0987129822' like '%' || identity;`

Comment: Is any solution ok, or is this about performance optimization? Is there a minimum length / minimum match length? Is the search pattern always at least as long as the longest matching `identity` or can the `identity` have additional leading characters? Like `XXX0987129822`? Your Postgres version?